# TableView not showing data until filter

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, observablecollection

I created this GUI in JavaFX

[image: Java FX TableView]

The problem is that when I try to run the `readList` function, after that, nothing will be shown in the table, but, if i try to filter with something, the data appear.

What I did wrong? Isn't the SortedList linked to the Filtered that is linked to the ObservableCollection that is watching the persons list?
Should not auto-update the `TableView` whenever I change something in that list?

That's the controller

```
public class LetturaAwpController {

    List<Person> persons= new LinkedList<Person>();

    ObservableList<Person> observablePerson = FXCollections.observableList(persons);

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUser;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtPass;

    @FXML
    private TextField txtFiltraId;

    @FXML
    private CheckBox chkMag;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> tblMain;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> colId;

    @FXML
    void doRead(ActionEvent event) {

        if(txtPass.getText().isEmpty() | txtUser.getText().length() < 6)
            return;
        if (persons== null)
            persons= model.readList(txtUser.getText(), txtPass.getText());
        else
            persons.addAll(model.readList(txtUser.getText(), txtPass.getText()));
    }

    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        FilteredList<Person> filteredPerson= new FilteredList<>(observablePerson , p-> true);

        colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("idApparecchio"));    

        txtFiltraId.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue)-> {
            filteredSlot.setPredicate(person-> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()){
                    return true;
                }

                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if(person.getIdApparecchio().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                    return true;
                } else if (person.getNomeModello().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
        });

        SortedList<Person> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredPerson);

        // 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tblMain.comparatorProperty());

        // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
        tblMain.setItems(sortedData);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't the SortedList linked to the Filtered that is linked to the ObservableCollection

Yes and yes (Although there is no `ObservableCollection`, it's **`ObservableList`**)

> that is watching the persons list?

No

The `ObservableList` is not watching the list that is passed to [`FXCollections.observableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-), it creates a `ObservableList` that is backed by the `List`. Modifying the backing list will not notify listeners added to the `ObservableList`; the `ObservableList` just uses the backing list to store it's elements. `FilteredList` relies on a listener however.

This means: Do not access the backing list with write accesses. Modify the `ObservableList` instead:

```
observablePerson.addAll(model.readList(txtUser.getText(), txtPass.getText()));
```

Furthermore the `if (persons== null)` check is unnecessary, if you initialize the field and never modify it. Also simply replacing the field would result in the `ObservableList` being backed by a list different to the one stored in the field...